# code from matlab into c++

Tags: c++, matlab, plot, dynamic-allocation

Is there any best approach or template to follow, while doing this? 
I mean two things in particular, because for me it is problematic to imagine how it would go in c++:

- expanding arrays on go, where they are expanded during program and i dont know whethere the final size will be e.g. 10 or 100000.
- plots. I have never done any plot in c++ as I always have been doing it in matlab when necessary.

So what templates or rules should I follow, and how could I cope with those two things? 
I found that eigen library would be useful for matrices (dynamically expanding also?), but as I am not sure, want to ask first to be sure of a right approach. Nothing i know about plots.

Please add some link for me to learn from, if useful.
Thanks!

Comment: `Eigen` is certainly a very good choice as long as your are going to transform MATLAB code into C++. You'll find many familiar routines in Eigen, but what's more important is that it imposes object-oriented design, the one that you don't even have in MATLAB (in most cases). That would be a good practice for you: how to think in terms of classes, since mathematical objects like matrices, vectors, quaternions, rotations, etc. which are extensively used in numerical analysis and computer visualization are a perfect subject of object-oriented approach.

Comment: @josh130 just curious but what are your goals here? To increase program speed? To make a gui/program accessible to everyone? To broaden your horizons?

Comment: @jucestain i want to make my code faster, to be more real-time alike. so i was thinking if such simple and short matrix operations in matlab, when they get so complicated to be written in c++ (changing size) really make it faster, not slower.

Comment: @Haroogan: OOP has been officially supported in Matlab since 2008a - but you still can get by without writing any class of your own, of course.

Comment: @josh130 Have you considered mex? This would allow you to write some bottleneck routines in c++ while still remaining in the matlab environment and continue allowing you to use their plotting functions. Also, depending on what you're doing (i.e. if the bottlenecks are large matrix multiplications or FFTs) you will not beat matlab. If the routines you want to speed up are a bunch of small operations within a large for-loop then mex will work great.

Comment: @Jonas: Sure, but I still find MATLAB style to very procedural and boilerplate. Personally, I use MATLAB only to rapidly test some assumptions and outline basic algorithms, especially when I do some numerical stuff. After I've done the sketch, I immediately switch to C++, NumPy or whatever alternative is the most suitable.

Comment: @Haroogan: No problem, all I wanted was to dispel a possible misconception. It's a good idea to do the production code in whichever language that makes you most productive.

Comment: @jucestain thing for me is the 2nd one, small operations inside of big loops, and as matlab was rapid prototyping for me, I'd like to switch to c++ code, but still some matrix operations i might do by calling matlab though, do you recommend some particular source to learn about mex functions (with some simple examples)?

Comment: @josh130 http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/getting-started-with-mex-a-short-tutorial/ is what I used when I first started. You can also debug it with visual studio too if you're using windows. I'd say the only downside of mex is that run time errors generally cause matlab to crash. This can be annoying at times but the fact that you can remain in the matlab environment is very nice and worth the trouble IMO.

Comment: @jucestain many thanks for your personal advice! how do you cope then with runtime errors? (and debug errors, sincedebug mode should span now to both matlab and VS (windows is ok for me)

Comment: @josh130 Well, I try as hard as possible not to make mistakes I guess lol. But if there is a run time error, it's almost always an access violation so I try to keep that in mind. I'll just step through the program until it crashes and then usually the last thing it hits will give insight to why it crashed. There's probably a better way, but regardless I haven't had huge issues with this. Usually you only mexify little segments so they should be pretty manageable. If you're mexifying large chunks then yea, porting the entire thing to c++ is probably better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **expanding arrays on go, where they are expanded during program and i dont know whethere the final size will be e.g. 10 or 100000.**

The solution to this is simple: look up `std::vector` (or `std::deque`) both provide this behaviour. (With "subtle" differences between a deque and a vector).

- **plots. I have never done any plot in c++ as I always have been doing it in matlab when necessary.**

For this you'll have to search for a library that can do this, first you'll have to look into a graphical window library such as Qt. And then you'll have to look up some library that can plot data in a graph form.
Though for this matlab will probably always be the "easier/better" choice; C++ has nothing to help you with this.

Also remember: first learn the language, then learn libraries!

Comment: thank you! I learnt much of a syntax for both languages. Mostly in theory unfortunately, but at least I grasp general idea of how programs should look like. First that came to my mind was dynamic allocation, thanks for this much nicer idea using STL, Ill check it. To Qt, do you recommend some good tutorial for what I need? If not i just take one i find in the internet. If i understand good, apart from Qt i have to find some 2nd library to plot data on graphs that are produced via Qt, right?

Answer (score 1):

For plotting using QT, [QWT](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) is basically all you need as it provides all the non trivial kind of charts one may need.